# ASK-CLI deploy not working for hosting 'AWS with CloudFormation' - Alexa region "default": Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have performed `aws configure` and `ask configure` after installing ask-cli.
While setting up new skill using `ask new` selected NodeJS, AWS with CloudFormation.
Trying to deploy the skill using `ask deploy`, getting `[Error]: CliError: The CloudFormation deploy failed for Alexa region "default": Access Denied`.
Tried setting the region in *~/.aws/config* and in *~/.aws/credentials*, still running into same error.
What should be done to fix the issue?

Skill creation
[image]

Error deploying skill
[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution? If yes, please share.

Comment: I haven't found any solution

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to deploy.

After running `aws configure`, I called `ask new`, and I think the solution was to not select *AWS With CloudFormation* but *AWS Lambda*:
[image: screenshot]

I wanted to use an existing skill that I previously created in the web UI. So I created two folders: `lambda` and `skill-package`. Then I used `ask init` saying I don't want to use *AWS CloudFormation* to deploy:
[image: screenshot]

Next, I added my region in `ask-resources.json`, under *skillInfrastructure*:

```json
{
  "askcliResourcesVersion": "2020-03-31",
  "profiles": {
    "default": {
      "skillMetadata": {
        "src": "./skill-package"
      },
      "code": {
        "default": {
          "src": "./lambda"
        }
      },
      "skillInfrastructure": {
        "type": "@ask-cli/lambda-deployer",
        "userConfig": {
          "runtime": "nodejs12.x",
          "handler": "index.js",
          "awsRegion": "eu-west-1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I finished with `ask deploy` that worked!

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when the AWS IAM user I linked with `ask configure` didn't have the full permissions. To fix this, you need to go to IAM and update the permissions of the user linked to the CLI to this: https://github.com/openhab/openhab-alexa/issues/509#issuecomment-1167337129.

For my purposes, I generalized the policies a bit (since I'm just using the CLI in a dev environment) and just adding the following policies worked for me:

- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AWSCloudFormationFullAccess
- AWSLambda_FullAccess
- CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
- IAMFullAccess

Comment: It's definitely unintuitive that all these permissions are needed, and that I had to get them from a GitHub issue instead of from the docs or from the CLI error message.